# Probability regarding 3 random toppings on a pizza

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

At Luigi’s House of Random Pizza, you can order only one thing: A medium pizza with three
random topping layers chosen by Luigi himself. Luigi has the following toppings: Pepperoni,
Pineapple, Mushroom, Anchovie, Onion, and Jalepeno Peppers. For example, you might get:
Pepperoni-Onion-Mushroom, or maybe Mushroom-Pepperoni-Onion (the order of the layers mat-
ters to Luigi) or if you are especially lucky then Anchovie-Anchovie-Anchovie. I am not sure if my thought process is correct for both of these.

1. What is the probability that you get a pizza with either two or three distinct toppings? (For
   example, Mushroom-Onion-Mushroom or Pepper-Onion-Mushroom.)

What I tried for this is that the probability for more than 1 topping would be equal to: $1 - P(1~\text{topping}) = 1 - \dfrac{6}{6^3} = 0.97$.

2. What is the probability that Luigi gives you a pizza with exactly two distinct toppings
   (occurring in any order)?

I am unsure of my logic for this but I believe that the equation would be: $P(2~\text{toppings}) = 1 - P(1~\text{topping}) - P(3~\text{toppings}) = 0.97 - P(3~\text{toppings})$. What would I do to find the probability for $P(3~\text{toppings})$ in order to use the equation to solve for $P(2~\text{toppings})$?

Comment: Yes, this is right. For the second one, assuming you definitely get $3$ toppings, then there are $3$ possibilities regarding the distinctness of the toppings, either you have all the same, $2$ distinct toppings or all different toppings. Therefore $\mathbb{P}(\text{one distinct topping}) + \mathbb{P}(\text{two distinct toppings}) + \mathbb{P}(\text{three distinct toppings}) = 1$

Comment: Yes, I have the equation but I am unsure how to calculate the probability for three distinct toppings in order to use the equation to solve for probability of two distinct toppings.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought when you said "I believe..." that you weren't 100% sure on whether the formula was correct. So imagine you have the blank pizza in front of you, how many choices for the first topping do you have? Once you place this first topping, how many choices for the second topping do you have, keeping in mind that you can't use the same topping more than once? Finally, once you have placed $2$ distinct toppings, how many options are left for the final topping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first answer is correct. Let the first toppings be any one of the six. The probability that the remaining two toppings are the same as the first is $~ \displaystyle \frac 16 \cdot \frac 16 = \frac 1{36}$

So the probability that there are two or three distinct toppings is,

$ \displaystyle  1 - \frac{1}{36} = \frac{35}{36}$, same as you obtained.

For the second question, note that there are two cases - i) if the second topping is same as the first then the third has to be from the remaining $5$ toppings ii) if the second topping is different than the first then the third topping is either from the first or the second. So the probability is,

$ \displaystyle \frac 16 \cdot \frac 56 + \frac 56 \cdot \frac 26 = \frac{5}{12}$

You could have also subtracted the probability of three distinct toppings from the answer to the first question. The probability of three distinct topping is,

$ \displaystyle \frac 56 \cdot \frac 46 = \frac 59~$ and

$ \displaystyle \frac {35}{36} - \frac 59 = \frac{5}{12}$